# Deselecting Pivot Table Items Error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to use the code in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768110/deselect-all-items-in-a-pivot-table-using-vba), but I keep getting the runtime error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method" for the line

```
ActiveSheet.PivotItems(1).Visible = True
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Full Code:

```
Sub DeleteAllFields()
    Dim i As Long
    ActiveSheet.PivotItems(1).Visible = True
        For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.PivotItems.Count
            ActiveSheet.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        Next
End Sub
```

Full disclosure - I am a novice VBA user.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error relates to you using `.PivotItems()` with the object `ActiveSheet`.

The `PivotItems()` property is part of the `PivotFields()` object so you would need something like:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Example Field").PivotItems(1).Visible = True
```

Comment: Hi Jordan, thanks for the response. I'm still a bit confused though. Why would you need to call out the pivot field is the idea of the code is to hide all of the fields except i = 1?

Comment: You're basically just showing rows in a pivot table, if you haven't already hidden any rows it won't make any difference however if you set `.Visible = False` then it will hide a row. You can loop through the Pivot Items using the index number e.g. `.PivotItems(i)` and check the `.PivotItems(i).Name` for a criteria and hide or show based on this - this is usually what this function is used for.