# VBA Filter error

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a filter field called week_of_year (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....), another pivot field year(2012,2013,2014), the vba code belows filter on the current week and year of 2014/2015 and hide everything else. But the problem is the code loops each record and runs slow when it comes to big pivot table. Im trying on a new code but encountering some error.

```
Sub datefilter()
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("LO").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Dim dd As Integer
dd = Format(Date, "ww")
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pf1 As PivotField
Dim PI As PivotItem
Set pf =              

Worksheets("LO").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("week_of_year")
Set pf1 =       
Worksheets("LO").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("year")
PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters
For Each PI In pf.PivotItems
 If PI.Name = CStr(dd) Then

    PI.Visible = True
Else
    PI.Visible = False
End If
Next

For Each PI In pf1.PivotItems
 If PI.Name = "2014" Or PI.Name = "2015" Then
    PI.Visible = True
Else
    PI.Visible = False
End If
Next
End Sub
```

New code that I develop is:

```
Sub datefilter1()
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("LO").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Dim dd As Integer
dd = Format(Date, "ww")
Dim pf As PivotField
Set pf =        
Worksheets("LO").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("week_of_year")
pf.PivotFilters.Add2 xlValueEquals, 3
End Sub
```

The code failed at

```
pf.PivotFilters.Add2 xlValueEquals, CStr(dd)
```

I also tried:

```
pf.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:= xlValueEquals, Value1 := CStr(dd)
```

The error is Invalid procedure call or argument.Any idea How I can fix this error?????

Any faster way to filter on multiple filter criteria? Thanks!

Comment: Pivot Table Report Filters work a bit differently than Row / Column label filters. Unfortunately, you are stuck with the loop method.

Comment: no way.....the loops take forever. Im trying out Currentpage method. Any idea with that?

Comment: Scott is correct.  The CurrentPage method only shows ONE pivotItem, not multiple and cannot be altered to show more than one except by using the looping method.  If you want to do something different, perhaps you could use a helper column on your data (weekRange1 corresponds to weeks 1-8) and filter to that using the currentpage option.

Comment: What about the pivotfilter.add method?? What did I do wrong with it? Maybe that method is faster than loop as well?  @OpiesDad

Comment: Per this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764504/speed-up-pivot-table-filtering-vba-code it seems that it is not possible to prevent the pivottable from updating while you are looping through.  I tried all of the answers and none worked, and the OP never marked any as answer which indicates that they didn't work for him either.

Comment: As far as PivotFilter.Add2, I haven't used this, and similarly received the same error you did.  Unsure why it isn't working.

Comment: PivotFilter.Add will only work if the field is either a value field or row or column field;  it doesn't work on a "Filter" field in the PivotTable.  To fix this, you need to make this a row/column in the PivotTable, which I'm guessing you don't want to do.  You may be able to group the items and then filter them this way.

Comment: See this post: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?46430-Group-pivot-items for how to group the items and then you could use the currentPage method with the group.

Comment: @OpiesDad The way I'm reading this question, the op actually *wants* to show just one Pivotitem in each field: the current week, and the current year. Which means PageFields are the way to go, and looping is not necessary. Also, it is absolutely possible to stop the PivotTable refreshing each time: you just need to set .ManualUpdate to TRUE while you make your changes, and set it back to FALSE afterwards. 

I have an article on filtering PivotTables efficiently at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ that is probably worth a read.

Comment: @jeffreyweir I tried to use the .ManualUpdate option, and it did not work for me in Excel 2013.  User in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764504/speed-up-pivot-table-filtering-vba-code also tried this to no avail (likely on an earlier Excel version).  Any reason why this might not be working for either of us?

Comment: @OpiesDad Nowhere at that other thread does it say that .ManualUpdate does not work. The OP at that other thread tried Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual which is a completely differet thing. The OP made no mention that PivotTable.ManualUpdate = FALSE was not working.

PT.ManalUpdate works just fine. Suggest you post your code here

Comment: @jeffreyweir In the second answer, it was proposed to use this option and the OP mentioned in comment that it did not work for them.  All I did was use PivotTable.ManualUpdate = TRUE and then set several pivotitems.visible = true/false.  Each time it set a new item to true/false, the pivottable updated.  I was stepping through the code line by line, so I suppose that could matter, but didn't think it would.

Comment: Where abouts in that thread did the OP mentioned in comment that it did not work for them?

Your issue is that you are stepping through the code. Just run it without stepping through it, and you will see that it works just fine. If you have an issue, you need to post your code.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Then the problem is stepping through the code.  I'll test it without stepping through the code.  In the second answer to the linked question, barrowc suggests using the .ManualUpdate property.  The OP, Ankit, comments, "I tried that but it didn't work."  They were potentially having the same issue I am, stepping through the code instead of just letting it run.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to filter on one value, drag the field of interest to the Report Filter pane, then you can do this very quickly without looping using the following code:

```
Sub FilterOnWeek()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField


Set pt = Worksheets("LO").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("week_of_year")

pf.CurrentPage = Format(Date, "ww")
End Sub
```

If for some reason this field absolutely must stay in the PivotTable as a row field, you can still filter without looping by the following method if you have Excel 2010 or later

1. Make a copy of the PivotTable, and drag the 'week_of_year' field
   in the copy to the Report Filter area
2. Set up a slicer on the week_of_year field on one PivotTable, and
   connect it to the other PivotTable via the Report Connections
   dialog. (Right click on the Slicer, select 'Report Connections')
3. Amend the above code so it runs on the 2nd PivotTable.

The Slicer will then sync the two PivotTables.

If you want to filter on **more than one** value, drag the field to the ROWS area, and use this:

```
Sub FilterOnWeek2()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim lStart As Long
Dim lEnd As Long


lEnd = Format(Date, "ww")
lStart = Val(Format(Date, "ww")) - 1

Set pt = Worksheets("LO").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("week_of_year")

With pf
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionIsBetween, Value1:=lStart, Value2:=lEnd
End With

End Sub
```

If for some reason you **don't** want this field  in the PivotTable as a row field, follow the same general approach as above: make a copy of the PivotTable, put the field that you want to filter on in the copy as a ROWS field, connect the fields of interest together as a slicer, hide the slicer somewhere, and amend the code so it runs on the copy of the PivotTable with the rowfield in it.

I recommend you read my article at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ if you want to learn more about efficiently filtering PivotTables.

Comment: Hi Jeff I actually took currentpage away from my code cuz it only allows one value, if I want multiple items they say it wont work. If I want the current week and previous week,would you know how to do that? Thanks!!

Comment: See my amended answer above.

Comment: Jeffrey thanks, that only capture two items, what if I want multiple items, only with date , but also with strings?any solution with that? I have three filters in my pivot all need to be coded, with date,value and multiple items. with that condition, will my only option be looping each record?? Thanks again!!!!!!

Comment: @Sailormoon You keep changing the requirements! Please click the link to my article above, as that does what you need. The code listing at that article is very long and very complicated, but very very fast. I'm also working on a commercial add-in that filters PivotTables very quickly, as per my post at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/11/17/filtering-pivottables-with-vba-deselect-slicers-first/ and I'll be releasing this soon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299073/filter-by-multiple-conditons-pivot-vba I created a new question, thats pretty much everything I need in there. If you have the answer for this I will appreciate a lot

Comment: sorry I didnt explain it right, for the first comment I had i used "Multiple items", and the current week and previous week is just an example. If I want to select more than two items, that code won't work.

Comment: Instead of starting a new thread, you should have just edited this one.