# Filter by multiple conditons pivot VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have four filters on a pivot table,week_of_year(1,2 to 52),date(1/1/2012 to 2/7/2016),year(2012 to 2016),city(newyork to san fransisco)

```
Sub datefilter()
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("test").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pf1 As PivotField
Dim PI As PivotItem
Set pf =              
Worksheets("test").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("week_of_year")
Set pf1 =       
Worksheets("test").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("year")
Set pf2 =       
Worksheets("test").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Date")
Set pf3 =       
Worksheets("test").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("city")

PvtTbl.ClearAllFilters

For Each PI In pf.PivotItems
If PI.Name = "7" Then
PI.Visible = True
Else
PI.Visible = False
End If
Next

For Each PI In pf1.PivotItems
If PI.Name = "2014" Or PI.Name = "2015" Then
PI.Visible = True
Else
PI.Visible = False
End If
Next

''Same for the Date,city, have multiple items selected as filter.
End Sub
```

This works but take forever to run, cuz its looping each record. Try to find a more efficient way to do it. Any one can use currentpage or pivotfield.add to achieve the same thing? Appreciate!!!Thanks a bunch!

Special request: the pivot table is linked to database. So when new date flashes in, need to select more date from the filter. For example, if 2/9/16 gets in,also need to select data <= 2/9/15 and only select data for 2015, neglect 2012,2013,2014. Looping each record is too cumbersome and takes forever to run.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a little more work with your raw data first. It sounds like you only want data with a few set conditions.

So, you could write VBA that drops a nested-if statement into a new column with the following logic:

`=if(or("YOUR FIELD"=2014, "YOUR FIELD"=2014),"Yes",if("YOUR FIELD"=7,"Yes","No"))`

Then filter by everything in this new formula column that equals "Yes", and you reduce the pivot filter to one switch.

If it's a larger data set and you don't want formulas eating up your memory, you could also use a For loop to accomplish the same effect. That's my preferred method actually.

Comment: you suggest to imbed another column on top of my link to database? still kinda slow performance. BTW, how do I use for loop?? Thanks for responding though

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution is to set up a Stored Procedure with dynamic procedures in the underlying database that will let you filter your data at the Database end.  That SP could then draw on a list in the spreadsheet. See http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-with-dynamic-parameters/

If that is not possible, my article at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ has code that will do what you want, as I've already outlined at [your other thread on this topic](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/)

Read that thread, and you will learn how to drastically reduce the amount of time it takes to loop through PivotItems and change their status.

Also, note that before you iterate through PivotItems you want to set PT. .ManualUpdate to TRUE while you make your changes, and set it back to FALSE afterwards to avoid the PivotTable refreshing after each and every change.