# Filtering a row in Pivot Table using user Input from excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

am trying to built a macro for a custom pivot table that will accept user input as filter. I have a working code for the same, the issue is its slow.

User Input is happening from a column on the excel, u can add as many rows as possible

My total line items in the Pivot Row is 425 (Variable can increase or decrease)

Total line items to be filtered (User Input) is 18 (Variable can increase or decrease)

Total time taken to complete the operation is **250 seconds**

```
Function FilterMultipleArray()

     Dim FilterArray As Variant, TotalRows As Long, ws As Worksheet

     TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    FilterArray = Application.Transpose(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Check Orders").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(TotalRows, 1)).Value)
    
    
     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot Sheet for custom orders")
     ws.Activate
    
    Dim myPivotField As PivotField
    Set myPivotField = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OrdersPT").PivotFields("Order No")
    myPivotField.ClearAllFilters
    myPivotField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    
    numberOfElements = UBound(FilterArray) - LBound(FilterArray) + 1
    
    If numberOfElements > 0 Then
        With myPivotField
            For i = 1 To myPivotField.PivotItems.Count
            j = 1

' This is the time consuming part

            Do While j < numberOfElements
                If myPivotField.PivotItems(i).Name = FilterArray(j) Then
                    myPivotField.PivotItems(myPivotField.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = True
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    myPivotField.PivotItems(myPivotField.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            Next i
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Guys is there a better way to go about this??

Comment: Some ideas here maybe: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

Comment: or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764504/speed-up-pivot-table-filtering-vba-code

Comment: You already cleared all filters on the field, so you do not need to set `.Visible = True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is faster:

```vb
Function FilterMultipleArray()

    Dim FilterArray As Variant, TotalRows As Long, wsPT As Worksheet
    Dim rngFilt As Range, wsFilt As Worksheet, pt As PivotTable
    Dim myPivotField As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
    
    Set wsFilt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Check Orders") 'ThisWorkbook?
    Set rngFilt = wsFilt.Range("A2:A" & wsFilt.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set wsPT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot Sheet for custom orders")
    wsPT.Activate
    
    Set pt = wsPT.PivotTables("OrdersPT")
    Set myPivotField = pt.PivotFields("Order No")
     
    myPivotField.ClearAllFilters
    myPivotField.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    
    For Each pi In myPivotField.PivotItems
        'match is faster
        If IsError(Application.Match(pi.Name, rngFilt, 0)) Then
            pt.ManualUpdate = True '####
            pi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
    pt.Update
    
End Function
```

You already cleared all filters on the field: all items should be visible already, so you only need to change the ones which need hiding.
Setting `ManualUpdate` should give you a speed improvement, and Match against a range is faster than an array loop.

Comment: it finished in 20.02 seconds.. How??? This is so amazing... Ur amazing.. Match is amazing..

Comment: can we use match to find words with special formatting?? for eg i want to search for the word "blah 1", that's of Arial Font, Style is bold, size is 8. Is this possible??

Comment: I  couldnt tag u in the first comment

Comment: Pretty much whatever you can do via the UI you can do with VBA.  Excel is more limited than (eg) Word though when searching for a specific format.  It would be slightly slower but you can just search for the text then check the formatting of each found cell.